# Need to override child's overflow property by parent

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I need to override child's css property. In my case child element is dynamically creating(highcharts) and it is having overflow:hidden property. I need to override that property to make child element should overflow when excess data.

Comment: I don't think that this issue is related to using the Highcharts library.

Comment: Yes, this is not related to the high chart, but high chart div having overflow: hidden property. because of that, I am unable to add a scroll to that

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly, use props to change property can be work

```
Parent(){
  <Child overflow="auto" />
  <Child overflow="hidden" />
}

Child(props){
  <div style={{overflow: props.overflow}}>
    overflow
  </div>
}
```

Comment: We are not having a way to add props

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution. added 'overflowX: scroll' style to the first child div. It worked.